# javascript regex replace horizontal ellipse

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm importing a feed into an app and have a regex replace setup to turn url strings into hyperlinks. Every once in a while a horizontal ellipse `…` is attached to a link `http://example.com/home.html…` and get's pulled into the hyperlink href. How can this be removed? Below is my current replace.

`str.replace(/(http[^\s]+)/, '<a href="$1" target="_blank">link</a>')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
a = a.replace(/… +$/, "")
a.replace(/(http[^\s]+)/, '<a href="$1" target="_blank">link</a>')
```

Comment: `/(http[^\s]+)…/` – that won’t match any URLs any more that are _not_ followed by `…` – at least you should make the `…` optional.

Comment: *g* and *i* flags might help too, maybe the OP wants to process more than one URI.

Comment: Doh. Edited with a more legible way to do it anyway.

Comment: I guess regex can't match ellipse, but I got it working with unicode. `replace(/\u2026/, "")` Thanks y'all.